# How to fix the "Unable to calculate upgrade" issue when upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10?

Tags: upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade to 12.10 ever since it was released today but I keep meeting this error:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
This can be caused by:  
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu  
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu  
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
```

I've tried updating all the currently installed software, removing all the extra PPAs, downgrading the files installed from xorg edgers' ppa but I haven't been able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed mine by removing ppa packages I had installed using ppa-purge

I knew I needed to do this by checking the logs in /var/log/dist-upgrade/
at the end of the apt.log file youll see what was confusing it.  In mine it was a video driver, and i was running several upgrades, so I did:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webapps/preview
sudo ppa-purge ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo ppa-purge ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:glasen/intel-driver
```

the last one - the glasen driver - seems to have done the trick for me.  Upgrade is now proceeding as normal.

Answer (score 28):

As stated [here](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/04/29/upgrading-ubuntu-10-04-lts-to-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) , removing PPA sources does not work every time.

You need to uninstall offending packages.
you can find them with:

```
grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
```

Mine was an xorg package. I removed it with the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-all
```

and then the upgrade could continue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out WHERE the broken packages were.  That was the key to my successful upgrade to 13.10.

Comment: Yes! All was couse of xserver-xorg-*. (`apt-get remove xserver-xorg-*`)

Comment: Instead of "broken", a more specific keyword to use in your search of offending packages is "can't be satisfied".

Comment: I get a very long list of about 100 packages.

Comment: I had well over 900, and even a few hours of culling them via detectivework on the apt.log only got me to around ~350. Knowing the problem in my case was all the stuff I'd installed manually over the years,  I finally buckled down and simply deleted all "Installed (local or obsolete)" entries listed in Synaptic's "Status" tab.  Yes, I knew it would require chroot'ing from the Live CD to apt-get all the stuff to get an operational system again -- but it did work.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The apt.log file just shows apt working through the dependency list. Do not blindly remove the "Broken" packages. Look in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` to find the real error instead.

Answer (score 23):

### For a "NonPainful" release upgrade.

- Before proceed, check if the new release is available for upgrade. Open a terminal and give this command

  `do-release-upgrade -c`

If yes, proceed:

- Remove all the external PPAs you've added.

  From Software-Center > Edit > Software Sources > Other Software. Do
  not only un-tick ,but delete them.
- Then close all the graphical applications and open only a terminal.(Fullscreen is better) 
  Give the bellow commands

  ```
  sudo apt-get update 
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```
- Then give the bellow commands to do a little housekeeping

  ```
  sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ { print $2 }')
  ```
- Then you can procceed with the upgrade

  ```
  sudo do-release-upgrade
  ```

Do not navigate or open windows or programs during the upgrade.

Be patient until the upgrade finish.

Friendly:
Do not run (or rush) to upgrade from the day one. Upgrade from the day two or three(better).

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is extremely educating! However, I fixed my issue before reading your reply. I had to enable the conflicting PPAs then purge them to get the job done.

Comment: what does `sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ { print $2 }')` do?

Comment: @whoKnows
Sorry for the late answer. This will search-find and remove all the leftovers that have been marked for removal, but they have not been removed yet. That is what 'rc' means.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the one below did

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve the problem without removing any packages. On the settings for the update manager, I unchecked all of the Ubuntu Software options, leaving only the first box checked -- "Canonical-supported free and open-source software (main)".

Comment: I upvote for this answer because it solved a problem. It was enough to uncheck „Community-maintened ... (universe)“. I had exactly the same problem as described on topic. I was upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04.1 with „Software Updater“.

Comment: This worked for me, the comments about purging packages didn't.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error message on upgrading, albeit between different versions — I was doing 14.04 Trusty -> 16.04 Xenial — but I think this tip may be useful to other people who get the same error, since it took me ages to figure out, and this answer comes up prominently in Google.

It's important to check if there is any error in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` - in my case, there was an error that saying that `postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1` was blacklisted from being removed, and the upgrade process was trying to remove it. Removing that package let me upgrade.

(n.b. `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` may mislead you by listing "Broken" packages which actually won't block the upgrade.)

This is also pointed in this similar question and answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/541406/13868

Incidentally, running `sudo ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` after the failed upgrade, can actually detect such problems and open [the corresponding bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/996916) in your web browser - that's what helped me to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks, very useful and still relevant info for 18.04 to 20.04 upgrade.

Answer (score -4):

```
sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

that worked for me.