# Ubuntu dist-upgrade failure from 13.10 to 14.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade

I have tried to upgrade Ubuntu in graphical mode from 13.10 to 14.04 but I've got this error:
"Could not calculate the upgrade"
What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Open 'Software Updater' and upgrade online. On slow connection it would take some time. Have patience. It would be seamless. All your apps would remain as it is.

Answer (score 0):

`dist-upgrade` is not a good choice for upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04.

try `sudo do-release-upgrade` for you upgrading, according to the official document here:

[Wiki on Upgrading](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html)

I upgraded to 14.04 successfully yesterday in this way.

---

update

if the speed of update is slow, the mirror site of ubuntu update has not gotten the 14.04 pacakge. try to change a mirror site:

open preferences -- software and update, 
change a website near your country listed in 'download from'.

And I also searched the keywork 'could not calculate the upgrade', try these suggestions if you still field to upgrade ubuntu.

[Could not calculate the upgrade, what happened?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-what-happened)

[How to fix the "Unable to calculate upgrade" issue when upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202730/how-to-fix-the-unable-to-calculate-upgrade-issue-when-upgrading-from-12-04-to)

Comment: Scotv I have tried your solution but didn't worked. This is what I've got: Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

Comment: hi @bazil, please see my update on the answer.