# How to remove a lot of broken packages (so that I can upgrade Ubuntu)?

Tags: upgrade, package-management

As I try to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.06, I ran into the "Unable to calculate upgrade issue", due to

> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
>   E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. This can
>   be caused by:
>   * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
>   * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
>   * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/230045/181686) shows how to remove all the "Broken" packages. But my list is very long (100+), and I can't possibly delete them all by hand.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Are you using PPAs? what is the output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Comment: I use a lot of PPAs, I can count 15+ running that commands. Do I have to lose them all? That makes the upgrading process quite painful.

Comment: Remove every single ppa using `ppa-purge`. otherwise you can't upgrade

Comment: Is there a way to save them and quickly import them back after upgrading?

Comment: Yes, save those files somewhere. after upgrading you can copy back only changing release name there.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log`. The broken packages are likely a misnomer, as apt is just working through the dependency list and probably finds the correct solution for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the Synaptic Package Manager; use

```
$ sudo apt install synaptic
```

to install Synaptic. After that, click `Custom Filters -> Broken` and mark all broken packages for removal. Finally, apply the changes and you should be prepared for the upgrade once you remove or temporarily disable all the PPAs.