# Cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I have the following Ubuntu version: 14.04.6 LTS and I'm trying to upgrade to 16.04 with

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This command fails reporting:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
This can be caused by:  
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu  
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu  
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
```

And /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log says:

```
2019-09-06 17:15:26,873 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver:::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages
```

My question is: how to identify and delete these broken deps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved: it was very useful to me [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202730/how-to-fix-the-unable-to-calculate-upgrade-issue-when-upgrading-from-12-04-to) in pointing out where packages were broken during upgrade.

I removed some packages reported here and from time to time re-trying `do-release-upgrade` util it succeded.

Another useful command to me was `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall`: I've uninstalled everything reported by this command.